# Installing Play Framework on Windows 8.1

Tags: java, scala, playframework, windows-8.1

I have been trying to install Play Framework on Windows 8.1 through "activator". When I ran `activator` script, it gave an error telling me it couldn't find Java. I didn't want to mess with environment variables so I ran the jar file inside the "activator" directory but now I get such error as below.

```
C:\activator-1.2.10>java -jar activator-launch-1.2.10.jar
java.lang.RuntimeException: Property 'activator.home' has not been set
        at activator.properties.ActivatorProperties.requirePropertyWithOverrides
(ActivatorProperties.java:64)
        at activator.properties.ActivatorProperties.ACTIVATOR_HOME(ActivatorProp
erties.java:118)
        at activator.ActivatorLauncher.openDocs(ActivatorLauncher.scala:42)
        at activator.ActivatorLauncher.displayHelp(ActivatorLauncher.scala:72)
        at activator.ActivatorLauncher.run(ActivatorLauncher.scala:32)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:129)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:36)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:19)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:44)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
```

It tells me that activator.home is not set but I didn't install the Play yet. Do I have to add something to system variables?

Comment: If it can't find java then there is something wrong with your environment variables. There is nothing wrong with making changes to environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `activator.bat` to start activator instead of the `java -jar` command

Answer (score 0):

You could run this command (Maybe wit admin privileges):

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java ACTIVATOR_HOME=C:\activator-1.2.10 -jar activator-launch-1.2.10.jar
```

Alternative way could be:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java -jar -dACTIVATOR_HOME=C:\activator-1.2.10 activator-launch-1.2.10.jar
```

Those command will not affect any environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up $JAVA_HOME environment variable first, to do so:

1. Right click at windows button on the left-bottom part of screen, choose 'System'
2. Click 'advanced system settings' from left sidebar.
3. Click 'Environment variables'
4. in the bottom part (system variables), 'ADD New', and then
5. use JAVA_HOME as name, and path to jvm folder as value.

You should be able to run you activator from system console.